# Incorrect results returned by postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, postgresql-9.1

I ran the following commands in posgresql 9.6:

```
./bin/createdb testSpatial
./bin/psql -d testSpatial -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis;"
create table test(name character varying(250), lat_long character varying(90250), the_geom geometry);
\copy test(name,lat_long) FROM 'test.csv' DELIMITERS E'\t' CSV HEADER;
CREATE INDEX spatial_gist_index ON test USING gist (the_geom );
UPDATE test SET the_geom = ST_GeomFromText(lat_long,4326);
```

On running: `select * from test;` I get the following output:

```
name |                                                                                          lat_long                                       
                                                   |                                                                                            
                                                  the_geom                                                                                      

------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------
 A    | POLYGON((-0.061225 -128.427791,-0.059107 -128.428264,-0.056311 -128.428911,-0.054208 -128.426510,-0.055431 -128.426324,-0.057363 -128.42
6124,-0.059315 -128.425843,-0.061225 -128.427791)) | 0103000020E61000000100000008000000D42B6519E258AFBFBE50C076B00D60C07DE9EDCF4543AEBFBC41B456B
40D60C08063CF9ECBD4ACBFA1BC8FA3B90D60C07BF65CA626C1ABBF58AD4CF8A50D60C0BF805EB87361ACBFFFAF3A72A40D60C0B83A00E2AE5EADBF4D81CCCEA20D60C01F1153228
95EAEBF60C77F81A00D60C0D42B6519E258AFBFBE50C076B00D60C0
 B    | POINT(1.978165 -128.639779)                                                                                                             
                                                   | 0101000020E61000002D78D15790A6FF3F5D35CF11791460C0
(2 rows)
```

After this I ran a query: To find all "name" which are within 5 meters of each other. For doing so, I wrote the following command.

```
testSpatial=# select s1.name, s2.name from test s1, test s2 where ST_DWithin(s1.the_geom, s2.the_geom, 5);
 name | name 
------+------
 A    | A
 A    | B
 B    | A
 B    | B
(4 rows)
```

To my surprise I am getting incorrect output as "A" and "B" are 227.301 km away from each other (as calculated using haversine distance here: http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/haversine/). Can someone please help me understand as to where am I going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined your geometry as follows

```
 the_geom geometry
```

ie, it's not geography. But the [ST_DWithin docs](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) say

> For Geometries: The distance is specified in units defined by the
>   spatial reference system of the geometries. For this function to make
>   sense, the source geometries must both be of the same coordinate
>   projection, having the same SRID.
>
> For geography units are in meters and measurement is defaulted to
>   use_spheroid=true, for faster check, use_spheroid=false to measure
>   along sphere.

So you are actually searching for places that are within 5 degrees of each other. A degree is roughly equal to 111km so you are looking for places that are about 550 km from each other rather than 5 meters.

Additionally, it doesn't make much sense to store strings like `POINT(1.978165 -128.639779)` in your table. It's completely redundant. It's information that can be generated quite easily from the geography column.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I a novice in postgres, how should I go about if I want to search all locations which are within 5 km of each other. Would use "the_geom geography" suffice instead of "the_geom geometry"